# Change what window displays (Mac - Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Sorry if this is a really basic question but I'm new to XCode and Mac development in general. I want to know how to get a window to change its contents without having to close and open a new window. For example:

```
- (IBAction)handlelock:(id)sender {
  [_window orderOut:sender];
  [_loginwindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}
```

But rather than closing _window and opening _login window, is there a way to make _window display the contents of _login when I click the button?

Answer (score 2):

Or, just swap the window's content views:

```
- (IBAction)handlelock:(id)sender {
     NSView *previousContentView = _window.contentView;
     _window.contentView = _loginwindow.contentView;
     _loginwindow.contentView = previousContentView; // just store it in the other window
}
```

Usually you wouldn't need multiple windows for this though, you would just have another view and swap it in.

Comment: haha how exactly do you make another view? (sorry im really just starting) :)

Comment: @haseo98 The easiest beginner way is to go into Interface Builder, drag in a "Custom View" from the palette, and in your main class, create an IBOutlet and connect it to that custom view, and you can now use your IBOutlet NSView as your "new view".

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  You could have a separate view in your xib file that contains what you want in your login window, and then call setContentView:loginView on you window, and that will swap out the old view for the new one.  You would want to have a property that points to the original view, if you want to be able to switch back to it.

Another way is to use a tab view -- if you don't like the looks of a tab view, there is a tabless tabview that doesn't look like it has tabs --- you would have one view in one tab, and the login view in another.

Comment: I'm sure there's some reason it's a terrible idea (something about it sounds fundamentally wrong), but I'm running with the tabless tabview because that sounds easiest.